# How get or instantiate Actor class?

Tags: java, akka, actor

The problem is I can not create Actor class directly:

**scala code**

```
MyActor extends EventsourcedProcessor with ActorLogging {
    // ...
}
```

**Java code**

version one

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyActor actor = new MyActor() //Exception here
       //akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [MyActor] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
    }
}
```

version two

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        final ActorRef actor = ActorSystem.create("helloakka").actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class), "actor");
        //What method to use there:
        //actor.get - ?
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

I need actor class only for diagnostic/experimenting sources of compile time errors with other class. I can not see all errors in IDE beacause they are not highlight, but when maven compile it fails. So I do some experiments to see where these errors apears and where do not.

Comment: `MyActor` is not valid Java.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: `MyActor` is scala nopt java, but usage will be from java. Also added exception description in sources. Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the underlying actor, you need to use `TestActorRef` from `akka-testkit`.

```
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef

val actorRef = TestActorRef[MyActor]
val actor = actorRef.underlyingActor
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/scala/testing.html#Obtaining_a_Reference_to_an_Actor

This should be used only in your tests and accessing an actor directly in production code is extremely dangerous and should not be done.